# How do i use the ProgressDialog from a Non-Activity Class on android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

In my app i have an activity(MainActivity.java) and a class(non-activity class - SubClass.java). The SubClass has a ProgressDialog. i will call the SubClass from the MainActivity.

**My question is How do i use the ProgressDialog from the Non-Activity Class(SubClass.java) from  the Activity Class (MainActivity.java)**

**I get Null Pointer Exception Error at setProgress() and package declaration.**

***I did the following things***

1) In the MainActivity i create object for the SubClass with constructor.

```
    SubClass pro = new SubClass(MainActivity.this);
    pro.call_fun();
```

2) In the SubClass : the whole coding ;

```
package com.progresss;  // Line No : 1 ; Shows Null Pointer Exception
public class SubClass {
Context context = null;
public static final int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS = 0;
private NotificationManager notificationManager;
private Notification notification;
private int progress_val = 0;
private String fileURL = "http://xxxxx.com/folder/sampleproject.apk";
private String destination = null;
private ProgressDialog downloadProgressDialog;

public SubClass(MainActivity progress_DialiogActivity) {
    this.context = progress_DialiogActivity;
}

public void call_fun(){
    new DownloadFileAsync().execute(fileURL);
}

    //  Updated APK File Download Task.
class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        ((Activity) context).showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
    //          Notification Coding     
        ...........
        notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;
    //          -------------------            
        notificationManager =(NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
        try {
    //              .......         
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error Report Download Manager", e.getMessage());
          }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
         progress_val = Integer.parseInt(progress[0]);
         .......
         downloadProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));   // Line No : 100 ; Shows Null Pointer Exception
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
        notificationManager.cancel(0);
    //          ((Activity) context).dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
        ((Activity) context).removeDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
        Log.e("Download", "Stop");

    //          Notification Coding     
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        .........
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);

    //          Open The Install App Activity(Intent) Here.            
        ........
    }
} // Async Task Class End

    //our progress bar settings
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS: //we set this to 0
            downloadProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            downloadProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading file...");
            downloadProgressDialog.setMax(100);
            downloadProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            downloadProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            downloadProgressDialog.show();
            return downloadProgressDialog;
        default:
            return null;
    }
  }
}
```

This is LogCat Error Message:

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.progresss.SubClass$DownloadFileAsync.onProgressUpdate(SubClass.java:100)
at com.progresss.SubClass$DownloadFileAsync.onProgressUpdate(SubClass.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:432)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The Progress Dialog Code Works good in an activity class. i guess ProgressDialog may not be initialized correctly. Please help me.

Comment: Did you check whether the onCreateDialog is called?

Comment: No onCreateDialog is Not Called. i add Log.e() in beginning of the onCreateDialog. it does not shown log.

Comment: Where have called onCreateDialog  ?? And even you code design is very bad...

Comment: @ Mohit Sharma , actually i need to do that process in non activity class. now i rearranged my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onCreateDialog` is not executed. Please move the code to `onPreExecute` Method .

`onCreateDialog` is call back method and it will be called in activity only , in your subcalss its just a method.

Comment: do you mean move the onCreateDialog code to OnPreExecute Method

Comment: you should move the code written inside the OnCreateDialog to OnPreExecute

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem. After I moved onCreateDialog to onPreExecute, it doesn't work.

I solved the problem after I changed `pro.call_fun()` to `pro.call_fun(MainActivity.this)`, and then 
created `downloadProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context)` in `pro.call_fun(MainActivity.this)`.

It works for me.